# How can one create a custom audio device to use with webRTC?

Tags: ios, objective-c, webrtc

The webRTC uses audioUnit. Which is defined in c++ as VoiceProcessingIO.mm
Is it possible to change the audio device through overriding or inheriting or may be even subclassing. I have been searching for a workaround to create and use my own audio device. Any kind of guidance is appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: Which implementation of WebRTC is it?

Comment: I have followed this [project](https://github.com/pristineio/webrtc-build-scripts).
After getting the source and compiling I used the framework the script file generated. 
But another problem is that it's huge in size. (1.23~1.25)GB.